# Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop and Rhythmbox

Tags: 13.10, rhythmbox, dlna

Ubuntu newbie just installing 13.10 desktop.  Does the version of Rhythmbox included with 13.10 natively support DLNA such that I can send music to my whole-house receiver.

If not natively, is there a way to make it do so?

Thank you very much.

Ken Traynham

Comment: Can't test it, but it should work. If you're after live streaming, you can setup PulseAudio to stream anything from your sound card or any source. That should be answered here.

Answer (score 1):

For some time now there has been a UPnP plugin based on Coherence(Now grilo) for Rhythmbox. It allows Rhythmbox to access UPnP/DLNA MediaServers on the network and will also export the Rhythmbox music collection to other UPnP/DLNA MediaRenderers such as the Sony Playstation 3.

Fist add grilo ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:grilo-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Then You can install it using

```
sudo apt-get install grilo grilo-plugins
```

Then go to pluings->grilo media browser. And configure it.

See more details here:

http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/240-ubuntu-precise-upnp-dlna-client

http://coherence.beebits.net/wiki/RhythmBox